# Powershell Arrays and Parenthesis

Tags: powershell, syntax

Coming from other programming languages, I would expect the following statements to all produce the same result. Can someone explain why the parenthesis make a difference here?

```
PS D:\>   "ab",      "cd"
ab
cd
PS D:\>  "a"+"b" ,  "c"+"d"
ab cd
PS D:\>  "a"+"b" , ("c"+"d")
ab cd
PS D:\> ("a"+"b"),  "c"+"d"
ab
c
d
PS D:\> ("a"+"b"), ("c"+"d")
ab
cd
PS D:\>
```

Comment: Check out Get-Help about_operator_precedence for a list of all the operators and their respective precedence in an expression.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The applicable rules are as follows:

- The `,` is a unary or binary operator that creates an array of the operand(s), and it has higher precedence than the `+` operator.
- The `+` operator can be used for numerical addition, string concatenation, and array concatenation. The data type of the ***left*** operand determines which type of operation is performed. If possible, the right operand is cast as the data type of the left operand; if not possible, an error is thrown. *
- Where precedence is equal, evaluation occurs left to right.
- Arrays are cast as strings by listing the elements separated by spaces.
- Parentheses, as you'd expect, have higher precedence than any operator, and cause the enclosed expression to be evaluated before anything outside the parentheses.
- The default output of an array object is a list of elements, one on each line.

<sub>* That explains seemingly inconsistent results such as that `"foo" + 1` evaluates to `foo1`, but `1 + "foo"` gives you an error.</sub>

So, let's take a look at your test cases, and analyze what happens following the logic explained above.

---

**Case I:**

```powershell
"ab", "cd"
```

This one is very straightforward: the `,` operator creates an array of two strings, `ab` and `bc`.

---

**Case II:**

```powershell
"a" + "b", "c" + "d"
```

This one seems counter-intuitive at a first glance; the key is to realize that `,` is evaluated before `+`. Here's how the result is obtained, step by step:

1. `"b", "c"` is evaluated first (due to `,`'s precedence over `+`), creating an array of the elements `b` and `c`.
2. Next, the `+` operator is applied to `"a"` and the array created in step 1. Since the left operand `"a"` is a string, a string concatenation is performed.
3. To concatenate a string with an array, the array is cast as a string. An array of `b` and `c` becomes the string `b c`.
4. Concatenating `a` with `b c` yields `ab c`.
5. Finally, `ab c` is concatenated with `d` to produce the final result, `ab cd`

---

**Case III:**

```powershell
"a"+"b" , ("c"+"d")
```

This yields the same result by coincidence; the evaluation occurs differently:

1. `("c"+"d")` is evaluated first, due to the parentheses. That's a plain vanilla string concatenation, which results in the string `cd`.
2. Next, the `,` operator is applied to `"b"` and the string from step 1, creating an array of the elements `b` and `cd`. (This is evaluated before `"a" + "b"` because `,` has higher precedence than `+`.)
3. Then, the `+` operator is applied to `"a"` and the array created in step 2. Since the left operand is a string, a string concatenation is performed.
4. The array of `b` and `cd` is cast as the string `b cd`.
5. The strings `a` and `b cd` are concatenated, resulting in the final output `ab cd`.

---

**Case IV:**

```powershell
("a" + "b"),  "c" + "d"
```

This is the most interesting test case, and probably the most counter-intuitive, because it yields results that may appear inconsistent. Here's how it's evaluated:

1. Similar to Case III step 1, `("a" + "b")` is evaluated first, producing the string `ab`.
2. The `,` is applied to the string from step 1 and `"c"`, creating an array of the elements `ab` and `c`.
3. The `+` operator is applied to the array from step 2 and the next token, `"d"`. This time, the left operand is an array, so an array concatenation is performed.
4. The string operand `"d"` is cast as an array of one element.
5. The two arrays are concatenated into an array of the elements `ab`, `c`, and `d`.

---

**Case V:**

```powershell
("a" + "b"), ("c" + "d")
```

By now, it should be easy to see what happens here:

1. `("a" + "b")` is evaluated as the string `ab`.
2. `("c" + "d")` is evaluated as the string `cd`.
3. The `,` is applied to the strings from steps 1 and 2, creating an array of `ab` and `cd`.

---

You can see the [precedence table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847842.aspx) with the command

```powershell
Get-Help about_Operator_Precedence
```

(Help doc names can be tab-completed, so to save typing, that's `help about_op`<kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd>)

Comment: Thanks for the awesome explanation. This totally cleared it up for me. Essentially, it was evaluating the expressions as so: `"a" + ("b", "c") + "d"` and `(("a"+"b"), "c") + "d"`

Comment: Cool. I'll add the analysis of the examples anyway, since SO questions and answers are intended to be useful as reference material for future searchers.

Comment: Microsoft needs to hire you to document everything.